# Can I ask a question here whose answer I did not get at math.stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, math-stackexchange

I have asked a question about solution of heat equation at math.stackexchange but no one answered. I think may be the question is too professional to be asked from learners. As this platform is for professional mathematicians, can I ask such question here which has been asked but not answered at math.stackexchange.

Comment: You certainly cannot ask a question whether you can ask a question. This is just cluttering the website.

Comment: You can post your question on mathoverflow meta

Comment: Or you can just link to the question (why on earth didn't you?). Your description of the clientele of Math.SE as mostly "learners" is slightly strange to me; there are many teachers and research mathematicians there. What is far more likely in my opinion is that your question got lost amid the high volume and traffic (and wasn't fruit hanging low enough for anyone to give an immediate quick answer).

Comment: Is this the question? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1680321/applying-fourier-cosine-transfer-method-with-this-neumann-boundary-condition-f

Comment: @ToddTrimble Yes exactly. This is my question